Trump says he wants to get revenge against Cheney. What could he possibly charge her with?
What could he possibly charge her with, given that she didn't do anything illegal or even wrong?
Would it be something specific like a fake bribe charge, or something general like "corruption of the government" or "helping the enemy" or Treason?

Nothing
The President of the United States cannot make criminal charges.
That said, it is possible that the people he installs at the various positions in the government which do have such authority (e.g.: US attorneys) will bring some charges or other. Whether those hold up in court is a different question.
She earned the irk of the GOP for working to uncover the truth about what happened during the January 6th events, and in particular for her role in convincing Cassidy Hutchinson to come forward with her testimony.

Your question is premised on the "she didn't do anything illegal or even wrong."
Taking that to be the case, you then ask what this person could "possibly" be charged with.
In one sense: nothing — if you mean to ask what offences are made out by their acts. Since if you accept your premise, no offences were actually commited.
In another sense: any existing criminal offence — since you seem to assume no wrong has been done and the charges would be "fake."
If instead you're asking what "fake" charges could plausibly be politically or popularly acceptable to enough people, that is not a question about the law.
(Also, of course, it is not the President who would literally charge the offence, but I don't take that to be your question.)
